I am using below to pull GA4 data. But when i am adding certain dimensions like HostName/pagePath, its giving elevated numbers
I am using below to pull GA4 data. But when i am adding certain dimensions like HostName or pagePath, its giving elevated numbers( mostly for users and sessions) than what actual values are, My guess is it calculates duplicates. How to get accurate results ?

def run_report_for_single_day(client, property_id, report_request, date):
    """Run report for a single day."""
    date_range = [DateRange(start_date=date, end_date=date)]
    dimensions = [Dimension(name=dimension["name"]) for dimension in report_request.get("dimensions", [])]
    metrics = [Metric(name=metric["expression"]) for metric in report_request.get("metrics", [])]

    request = RunReportRequest(property=f"properties/{property_id}", date_ranges=date_range, dimensions=dimensions, metrics=metrics)
    try:
        response = client.run_report(request)
        return response.to_dict()
    except (GoogleAPICallError, RetryError) as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        return None

A sample Request : The following works perfectly with only Date and eventName dimensions, But when i add hostname and pagepath the numbers are crazy high.

{"dimensions":[{"name":"date"},{"name":"eventName"},{"name":"hostName"},{"name":"pagePath"}],"metrics":[{"name":"activeUsers"},{"name":"eventCount"},{"name":"keyEvents"},{"name":"screenPageViews"},{"name":"sessions"},{"name":"totalRevenue"}],"dateRanges":[{"startDate":"2024-04-02","endDate":"2024-04-03"}],"metricAggregations":["TOTAL"]}

I am trying to pull the request with accurate values

Let's say we have 10 sessions in last 28 days.
If we pull the dimension pagePath.

page A , 5 sessions
page B , 3 sessions
page C , 3 sessions

The reason why it shows 1 more session is because
If a user browse page A and page c within a session.
It will both count 1 on PageA and Page C.
So when you add the value from split rows => total 11
But on the report it will show the total is 10

How to identify those Extra sessions? when we aggregate over a longer period of time, the numbers of extra are really high.
